# javascript: closest number in the array on the bigger side

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
  var scrWidth = $window.width();
  var scrSizes = [320, 480, 640, 768, 1024, 1366, 1600, 1920];
  var theSize = 0;
  if (scrWidth >= 1920) {
    theSize = 1920;
  } else {
    theSize = scrSizes.find(function(element){return element > scrWidth});
  }
```

Is there a better way to get the closest bigger number out of the array or if the scrWidth is bigger than the biggest then take the biggest?
So for example with 500 it returns 640, and with 5000 returns 1920.
(and with old javascript only)

Comment: Given that the `scrSizes` array is sorted, you could do a binary search on the array, but for such a small array, it doesn't really matter. A linear search is completely fine.

Comment: In my views, what you did is the better approach, as I couldn't find a better way for this situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`|| 1920` can be added at the end for when `.find` results in `undefined` :

```js
var scrSizes = [320, 480, 640, 768, 1024, 1366, 1600, 1920];
var scrWidth = 12345;
var theSize = scrSizes.find(function(element) { return element > scrWidth; }) || 1920;

console.log(scrWidth, theSize);

var scrWidth = 320;
var theSize = scrSizes.find(function(element) { return element > scrWidth; }) || 1920;

console.log(scrWidth, theSize);
```

If the result should be 320 when `scrWidth` is 320, replace `>` with `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this quite neatly with [underscore's](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) `filter` method:

```
 function getNextHighestNumber(arr, number) {
      return _.filter(arr, function(val) { 
        return val > number 
      })[0];
    }

 getNextHighestNumber([2, 5, 12, 34, 56], 17);
```

Or vanilla JavaScript:

```js
function getNextHighestNumber(arr, number) {
    var max = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
        if (arr[i] > number) {
            return arr[i];
        }
        if (arr[i] > max) {
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
    
console.log(getNextHighestNumber([2, 5, 12, 34, 56], 17));
console.log(getNextHighestNumber([2, 5, 12, 34, 56], 57));
```

Comment: Well, it works with 17 but gives undefined with 57, where it supposed to return 56

Comment: @Коля Check it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try with small below code using map and min method and observe the result:

```
var scrWidth = $window.width();
  var scrSizes = [320, 480, 640, 768, 1024, 1366, 1600, 1920];
  var theSize = 0;
  if (scrWidth >= 1920) {
    theSize = 1920;
  } else {
var test = scrSizes.map(a=> Math.abs(scrWidth - a));
    theSize = scrSizes.find( a => a == scrWidth - Math.min(...test));
    theSize = theSize ? theSize : scrSizes.find( a => a == scrWidth + Math.min(...test));
  }
```

Thanks, :)

Answer (score 0):

The below function will give the closest number greater then the number supplied in argument, if its in the array else will return the number supplied in the argument because its greater then all the numbers in the array.

```
 function getNextHighestNumber(arr, number) {
          for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
            if (arr[i] > number) {
              return arr[i];
            }
          }
         return number
  }
```